# $A_1,...,A_n,...$ measurable sets such that: ... Then $ \lambda (\bigcup _{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) \geq 1 $.

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

$A_1,...,A_n,...$  measurable sets such that:

i) $\lambda (A_n) \geq 1/2 $ forall $k$

ii) $\lambda (A_s \cap A_k ) \leq 1/4 $ forall $k \neq s$

Then $ \lambda (\bigcup _{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) \geq 1 $.

Attemp:

We consider the metric Boolean algebra $^\mathcal{A } / _\sim$ defined from : $d(A,B) = \mu (A \triangle B)$ .

We know that $^\mathcal{A } / _\sim$ is complete and when $\mathcal{A}= \mathbb{R} $ then  $^\mathcal{A } / _\sim$ is also seperable.

Also we have that
$d(A_n,A_m) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n \neq m$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: 1) inclusion- exclusion 2) $\lambda(\bigcup_{k=1}^{2^N} A_k) \geq \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2^k}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quantitative approach to the problem:

Let $B_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$, and suppose $\lambda(B_n) \leq 1$ for a given $n$. Let $f_k$ be the indicator function of $A_k$. Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\left(\int_{B_n} 1 \,d\lambda\right) \left(\int_{B_n} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n f_k\right)^2 \,d\lambda\right) \geq \left( \int_{B_n} \sum_{k=1}^n f_k \,d\lambda\right)^2.$$
The second integral on the left satisfies
$$\int_{B_n} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n f_k\right)^2 \,d\lambda = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{B_n} f_k^2 \,d\lambda + \sum_{i \neq j} \int_{B_n} f_i f_j \,d\lambda \leq n + n(n-1)(1/4) = \frac{n(n+3)}{4}$$
while the integral on the right has $\int_{B_n} \sum_{k=1}^n f_k \,d\lambda \geq n/2$, and putting these together gives $\lambda(B_n) \cdot \frac{n(n+3)}{4} \geq \frac{n^2}{4}$, which implies $\lambda(B_n) \geq \frac{n}{n+3}$, so $\lambda(B_n) \geq \frac{n}{n+3}$ in any case.

Thus for each $n$, $\lambda(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k) \geq \frac{n}{n+3}$, from which it follows that $\lambda(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k) \geq 1$.

Comment: It is a nice proof. I have seen those tricks with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but somehow I did not think about that.

Comment: I thought about the problem in terms of probability, and only rephrased in terms of measure theory at the end. if the union had measure $x < 1$, then rescaling the measure to be a probability measure on the union, we would have $\mu(A_n) \geq 1/2x$ and $\mu(A_i \cap A_j) \leq 1/4x$, so the events $\{A_n\}$ would have constant-sized negative pairwise correlations. considering the variance of $I_{A_1} + \cdots + I_{A_n}$, there is a linear-sized positive contribution from the individual variances, and a quadratic-sized negative contribution from the covariances...

Comment: ...which gives a contradiction for large enough $n$, since the variance must be nonnegative. when rephrased in measure theory, the variance argument becomes an application of cauchy-schwarz.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for explaining your thought process.